# Finding elements on a website with a lot of AJAX with Selenium error StaleElementRefrenceException

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I am trying to scrape a racing website with Selenium that has a lot of AJAX refreshes. The website page is refreshed constantly with details about upcoming races and so whenever I try to get information about the races I keep getting a StaleElementReferenceException: "element is not attached to the page document". I am able to get the most recent race but every time I try to iterate through all races currently posted on the website and interact with these elements, I get the stale element error.

Here is some example html:

```
<div class="panel" role="tabpanel">
    <button class="panel__label" role="tab">
         <div class="label-content">
             <div class="left">
                  <div class="event">
                      <div class="primary-text">
                          Brisbane Cup
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="location">
                      <div class="primary-text">
                          AU ∙ Brisbane
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="race-class">
                      <div class="primary-text helpful">
                          <span class="racing-tag racing-tag--5 racing-tag--class">
                              Class V
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="distance">
                      <div class="primary-text helpful">
                          2000m
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
     </button>
</div>
<div class="panel" role="tabpanel">
    <button class="panel__label" role="tab">
         <div class="label-content">
             <div class="left">
                 <div class="event">
                     <div class="primary-text">
                         Charlotte National
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="location">
                       <div class="primary-text">
                           US ∙ Charlotte
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="race-class">
                      <div class="primary-text helpful">
                          <span class="racing-tag racing-tag--5 racing-tag--class">
                              Class IV
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="distance">
                      <div class="primary-text helpful">
                          1200m
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
     </button>
</div>
```

So from this HTML I am trying to extract the event name, location, race class and the distance for every race. But as mentioned, when I try to access this information the website will refresh the data and I will get a StaleElementRefrenceException when I try access each race and sometimes there can be 10+ displayed on the website. Below is what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath)
driver.get("https://zed.run/racing/events")

allRaces = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('panel')
ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)

for race in allRaces:
    # Waits for presence of event name. If I put .text after this it works for the first race panel
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)\
              .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.event > div.primary-text")))
    
    # Returns StaleElementRefrenceException
    raceLocation = race.find_element_by_css_selector("div.event > div.primary-text").text
    raceClass = race.find_element_by_css_selector("div.helpful > span.racing-tag").text
```

How can I iterate through each race panel and retrieve this data without getting a stale element reference exception?

Comment: sorry have updated to correct address. https://zed.run/racing/events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw there is a grid that is getting increased when we move to the end so accordingly, I've created my solution for it, Maybe it is not more efficient but you can try

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("Path_to_ChromeDriver")

driver.get("https://zed.run/racing/events")
```

I have tried to scroll till the last record with the help of the below loop it also helped me to avoid StaleElementReferenceException

```
second = 10
for i in range(0,second):
    if second >=20 : break #here the seconds can be increase or decrease for performing the scroll for particular second
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,800)", "")
    sleep(2)
```

Here we are trying to get the desired element and store it in the variable

```
heading = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion']//div[@class='primary-text']")
```

Here traverse on the available record and get the text

```
for i1 in heading:
print(i1.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

**Code**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("Path_to_ChromeDriver")
driver.get("https://zed.run/racing/events")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//button[text()='Accept'])[1])").click() 
second = 10
for i in range(0,second):
    if second >=20 : break
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,800)", "")
    sleep(2)      
heading = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion']//div[@class='primary-text']")

for i1 in heading:
print(i1.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

**O/P**

```
Dnipro Oaks 
UA ∙ Dnipro 
Grande Prêmio Olinda 
BR ∙ Olinda 
Mariupol Grand Prix 
UA ∙ Mariupol 
Whitney Handicap 
US ∙ Long Beach 
The Pakistan Grand Prix 
PK ∙ Lahore 
New Zealand Oaks 
NZ ∙ Napier 
The Japan Derby Challenge 
JP ∙ Edogawa 
Rising Sun Classic 
JP ∙ Itabashi 
The Champsionship Mile 
GB ∙ Coventry 
The Champsionship Mile 
GB ∙ Coventry 
Racing In The Life Artois 
BE ∙ Leuven 
Abu Dubai World Cup 
AE ∙ Abu Dhabi
```

You can enhance it as per the requirement

check the [O/P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJXDI.png)